# CSS - DL styling definition list with dt and dd on seperate rows

Tags: html, css

I am trying to style up a definition list with  on top row and there corresponding dd's on sitting directly below on a seperate line

**HTML**

```
<dl>
    <dt>Term 1</dt>
    <dd>Definition 1</dd>

    <dt>Term 2</dt>
    <dd>Definition 2</dd>

    <dt>Term 3</dt>
    <dd>Definition 3</dd>
</dl>
```

**CSS**

```
dl {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 30px;
}
dt, dd {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    width: 33%;
}
```

I need them to sit something like below:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a containing element (which `<dl>` does not provide or allow for) around each `<dd>` and `<dt>` pair, and without resorting to likely-brittle absolute positioning, I think you're going to find that you'll need different markup to accomplish that layout.

It's not quite as semantically clean as your original markup, since it splits up the `<dl>` into three separate definition lists, but [here's a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nzgw1sz9/).

Comment: Was hoping to not have to use any extra mark up, but since I can control the size and know the hight and width of each <dd> and <dt> I will try the absolute positioning method. Thanks for some great answers though